# How to debug .net Activex used from html

Tags: c#, activex, activexobject

I have an activex that I built with .net fw 4.0.
I use it from html page, and i would like to be able to debug it.
The problem is that when I attach to the iexplore process, it doesn't stop in the breakpoint.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your control is actually loaded (IE security and other settings). A breakpoint displays a tooltip why it's not working. Generally, here's what I usually do. Do a break and examine the Modules window in Visual Studio. If your assembly is not there, then it must be in another process (IE can spawn many). If it is there, but has no symbols loaded, then load the pdb manually from there after right clicking. If it says that the source or the pdb is not up-to-date, then clear the assembly download cache with `gacutil /cdl`.